# Jquery/javascript flash function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check out this piece of code:

```
var shipping = $('#shipping_cell');
var total = $('#total_cell');

flash_cell(shipping);
flash_chell(total);

function flash_cell(target){

    var background = target.css('backgroundColor');

    target.stop().css("background-color", "#ac4341").animate({ backgroundColor: background}, 1500);

}
```

When I run this code, only the `#shipping` cell flashes.

If I switch the lines `flash_cell(shipping);` and `flash_cell(total);` around, neither one flashes.

Why don't they both flash?

Edit - here is my html

```
<td id = 'total_cell'><%= view_in_preferred_currency(@order.total) %></td>
<td id = "shipping_cell">
                <% if @order.free_shipping? or @order.collection? %>
                  <%= view_in_preferred_currency(0) %>
                <% else %>
                  <%= view_in_preferred_currency(@order.shipping_option.price) %>
                <% end %>
              </td>
```

Comment: show your html please

Answer (score 1):

Fix your typo:

**flash_chell(total)** to flash_cell(total)